# Plotting datas on iPad using core plot

Tags: ios, core-data, csv, core-plot

I have large amount of data to be plotted on iPad using a core plot. The data is in a CSV file format. Currently I'm parsing the data and plotting it real time. The problem is i'm trying to read the file and store in an array inside the program and at the same time plot it. So there is no data inconsistency. The graph keeps going on and off. For a file size of 60k to 100k lines is good to use core data. Because the data is transferred live with a delay of 8 seconds or so.  Will there be any issues?

Comment: "going on and off"? You mean it flickers during rendering?

Comment: there are some portion of the data being plotted and some goes on and off. For example for a scatterplot, A to B to C. B to C is displayed and A to B disappears and reappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to get real time performance with 100k data points, especially on iOS. The device doesn't have enough pixels to display that many distinct points anyway. The flickering might be from the plot taking too long to draw and things getting out of sync.

You need to filter the data or only plot a subset, for example, only the first 500 points.

Comment: is it possible to hold the plot on the screen after plotting once and then delete the data array to refresh with the new set of values to continue the scatterplot?

Comment: any idea how iOS apps like AirStrip OB does it? They are using core plot too

Comment: There are plot methods to add and remove data values without reloading all of it. See the real time plot in the Plot Gallery app for an example of how to use them.